# Is there any way to play Tekken 3 multiplayer online?

Tags: tekken-3

My friend can beat everyone with Ogre. We want to test his skill against best players of the world. Is there some way to play Tekken 3 through internet with someone else?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any other way than **emulation** to achieve that. Emulation is simulating an electronic system on another one, in that case running a software imitating a PlayStation on a computer. Emulation is legal when you own a copy of the game.

I recommend to try [Romstation](http://www.romstation.fr/installation). It is an emulation manager, usually working pretty well out of the box. It comes with the most popular emulators for many consoles, packing everything in a nice interface.

The key feature is online play : RomStation has already a fully configured space to play online, available for many games, including [Tekken 3](http://www.romstation.fr/jeux/page/tekken-3-r671).

You also might be able to find other persons willing to play online with you, searching the internet for dedicated forums.

Comment: How do I play multiplayer on that website?

Comment: keep in mind that downloading a copy of the game from the internet is illegal under copyright laws, and asking for help/giving advice on the topic is generally banned on this site.

I do believe you are free to run the emulator with a ***copy of the game you own***. Any half decent emulator will be able to run the game directly from the disc.

Comment: Right, I got a little carried on. Sooo... @user31782, you'll just have to figure it out by yourself. That shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I've downloaded Romstation  software but I still don't know how to play over there. They seem to want me to download their 450 MB Tekken 3 file, but I already have other iso files on my pc which are of various sizes. One is 50 MB and another which runs psxfins emulator is of  450 Mb.

Comment: Well, PlayStation games usually are 400-700 MB per CD.

Comment: @Ealhad I've Tekken 3 iso file 26 MB too with all players unlocked. My question is, can I somehow use my PC's tekken 3 file to play on ROmstattion or do I have to download their file?

Comment: Can you run your 26 MB file with the emulator ? That would really surprise me, it should be way bigger.

Comment: @Ealhad At present I have 54 MB Tekken 3 iso file which runs on the emulator. I had a 26 or 28 MB file too but I've reinstalled the window. Perhaps I could find other small games for play station emulator.

Answer (score 2):

**Without emulation, no.**

Tekken 3 was exclusively ported to the original Playstation which had ***no internet access***. Most fighting legends were re-released on XBLA or PSN, but sadly there were no old Tekken games re-released on Xbox Live and the ones released as "PS1 Classics" on Playstation Network had nothing added, not even online play.

Comment: How with emulation?

Comment: Get a PSX emulator, first off. I personally recommend ePSXe. Then set it up for Kaillera play.

Comment: What is Kaillera play and how can I set up my emulator for it? I've many emulators already downloaded.

Comment: Kaillera is a group of servers that allow emulators to connect to each other. You can use this to play online in games that were made for consoles that never supported this. To set it up, refer to this: http://www.epforums.org/showthread.php?55490-How-to-use-kaillera-in-ePSXe Make sure to use ePSXe, as that's the best PSX emulator for online play.

Answer (score -1):

YOU COULD IT IS CALLED TK3 ONLINE. I play against other ppl online all the time. here is a tutorial on how to play tekken online . it comes with a download link as well .   http://www.honmaru.pl/index_en.php?id=tk3online